# Export failing when I try to export from HyperV on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, export, hyper-v

I right click on a Virtual Machine and click export, select a path and then I get this error:

```
[Window Title]
Hyper-V Manager

[Main Instruction]
An error occurred while attempting to export the virtual machine.

[Content]
Export failed for virtual machine 'Win7Pro'.

[Expanded Information]
Export failed for virtual machine 'Win7Pro' (87874C77-ED1B-47E9-89DE-A12EC2845FEB) with error 'The system cannot find the path specified.' (0x80070003).

[^] Hide details  [Close]
```

I did a bit of searching and tried some workarounds (like renaming the VM) and it had no effect.  How do I fix this? I have 7 or 8 VMs and this affects only the one I really want to export.

The only path I input is the export path, and that path works when it is used with other VMs in the list, so the problem seems to be within the VM configuration's paths, but I do not see any errors there and the VM starts and runs just fine.

Comment: Have you tried to clone the virtual machine then export the clone?  Of course you really don't have to export the virtual machine to move it or import it into a different virtual machine application.

Comment: Be sure to post an answer if you figure out a solution.  I don't think simply saying to clone the .VHD is goog enough for an answer :-)

Comment: There is no "clone" menu item, the closest equivalent is "export", the thing that is failing. These VMs were created in windows 8, and appear to be 1st generation VMs, and they DO NOT export, although they run fine.

Comment: I might be able to rescue it with "Edit Hard Disk Wizard".

Comment: Nope. Edit Hard Disk wizard will "clone" or "copy" the Virtual Disk but the Export VM feature is still broken. I suspect a Win 8.1 BUG.

Comment: You could in theory use say VMWare or Virtual Box to convert it, clone it, then convert it back to a .VHD file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  However I had my VM and VM hard disk stored in different locations. I fixed the export issue by moving the VM and VM hard drive into the same folder.